# Xcode nested Framework: Project header files not found

Tags: xcode, objectiveflickr

I am trying to build a Mac application that uses [ObjectiveFlickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr), and thus has it as a nested framework. I followed [the setup guide](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr#adding-objectiveflickr-to-your-mac-app-project) on ObjectiveFlickr's page. Everything works fine until I have to validate my archived application.

Validating gives me the ['not single-bundle application' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206536/archiving-project-in-xcode-incorrectly-creates-multi-application-bundle). The solution to that seems to be to set 'skip install' to YES and to move the project header files from public to projected, for the nested framework. But if I do so, the framework can not find it's internal header files and my main application can find ObjectiveFlickr.h. (Related question: Shouldn't I keep ObjectiveFlickr.h as a public header file, since my main application needs to be able to find that one?)

I guess the solution lies in setting up some correct search paths for both projects. I have tried following the suggestion mentioned in [Xcode 4 and nested projects — header files not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413338/xcode-4-and-nested-projects-header-files-not-found), but nothing has worked.

I am using Xcode 4.5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 and nested projects -- header files not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413338/xcode-4-and-nested-projects-header-files-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the header files for the library version of ObjectiveFlickr were already set to project and not public, so I chose to use the library instead of the framework version, following this guide: [Adding ObjectiveFlickr to Your iPhone App Project](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr#adding-objectiveflickr-to-your-iphone-app-project). It worked find even though I am developing a Mac app and not an iOS app.