# Problems archiving project with react-native-fbsdk

Tags: xcode6, react-native

I have managed to get [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) (core, login and share) all working in my project. I can build to devices without issue but if I try to create an archive from Xcode I get the error

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
```

I have followed the install instructions and create a virgin project and done it again to ensure nothing else could be causing this.

Similar Xcode related questions have come up blank for me too:

[Xcode 4 can't locate public header files from static library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543854/xcode-4-cant-locate-public-header-files-from-static-library-dependency/10855606)

[When archiving app Xcode complains about missing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528133/when-archiving-app-xcode-complains-about-missing-files)

[Xcode 4 and nested projects -- header files not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413338/xcode-4-and-nested-projects-header-files-not-found)

This makes me wonder if there's something else to to with FBSDK specifically that I need to do to get it to archive properly.

Has anyone got a project to archive with react-native-fbsdk? If so, how?

Note: I skipped the step regarding explicitly naming the path for static libraries as I do not know what the name should be; I do not know which the static library would be fbsdkcore (etc) or react-native/react.

Answer (score 1):

I appears that the repo had an error in its header search paths in 'release' distribution. The fix was to correct the xcodeproj in the plugin (A PR is currently going through for this) as outlined [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/21#issuecomment-139342562)

The following line is present in the debug distribution but not in release for any of the required xcodeproj's

```
"$(SRCROOT)/../../node_modules/react-native/React/**",
```

Adding this fixes the error.

[Full Source Code Alterations](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/30/files)