# Cocoalibspotify Ad Hoc build fails

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am running into an issue when building an Ad Hoc build of my app with cocoalibspotify.

I have followed the instructions for iOS: https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify#building---ios

I don't have any issues running the app with the Spotify framework in Simulator or on my device.

The issue is related to `$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/include`, which in gives me the following paths:

```
build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/include
build/Debug-iphoneos/include
build/Release-iphoneos/include
```

Removing `$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/include` from my **Framework Search Paths** doesn't really change anything, and of course I am still unable to Archive the app. I noticed the Cocoalibspotify project doesn't have an Ad Hoc configuration, maybe this is the issue? I've tried to solve it with [this related answer for a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7549237/118091) but without any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the included examples, which all archive fine. It's likely you're missing `"$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include"` from your User Header Search Paths.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for such a fast response!